# Template literals in API fetch don't pass data in Angular

Tags: angular, fetch, template-literals, template-strings

I have a fetch() function to collect data from Skyscanner API. It works fine until I use template literals. This results in getting `error 400`.

```
public departureAPI = "WAW-sky";

fetch(
    "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com/apiservices/browsequotes/v1.0/PL/
PLN/en-US/${departureAPI}/CDG-sky/2020-08-12?inboundpartialdate=2020-08-23",...
```

I also tried using Angular interpolation with `{{ departureAPI }}` but with same negative results. Thank you for any suggestions on how to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TO use template literals, use **``** instead of **""** such as ::

```
fetch(
    `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com/apiservices/browsequotes/v1.0/PL/
PLN/en-US/${departureAPI}/CDG-sky/2020-08-12?inboundpartialdate=2020-08-23`,...
```